# Number of ways to choose elements given that we can only choose them from sides?

Tags: combinatorics

Please explain what is the number of ways of choosing elements given that we can only choose the leftmost and rightmost and it is compulsory to choose either element such that all elements are chosen at the end.
for example.
given 5 elements such that 1 2 3 4 5 
we can choose in the order 
1 2 3 4 5  or
5 4 3 2 1  or
1 5 2 4 3  or
1 5 4 2 3.
and not such as 1 4 2 3 5 or 2 3 1 4 5 etc
How many such ways to choose exist?

Answer (score 1):

If you have $n$ elements in your list, for the first step, you have $2$ possibilities, mainly removing first or last element, it remains $n-1$ elements and again you can remove first or last. At each step, except the last, you have two possibilities so in total you have $2^{n-1}$ possibilities.

Comment: You meant at each step except the last.